# How to remove all instances of duplicated values from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I know there is `array_unique` function, but I want to remove duplicates. Is there a built-in function or do I have to roll my own.

Example input:

```
banna, banna, mango, mango, apple
```

Expected output:

```
apple
```

Comment: Your input and output seem to be csv strings.  Are your values always grouped together? or might they be in mixed order?  Thinking out of the box and very literally to your sample data, this will work: `preg_replace('~(\b[^,]+),? ?(?:\1,? ?)+~', '', $string);` https://regex101.com/r/ChL2HI/1/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`array_unique`](http://php.net/array_unique), [`array_diff_assoc`](http://php.net/array_diff_assoc) and [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff):

```
array_diff($arr, array_diff_assoc($arr, array_unique($arr)))
```

Comment: What a bizarrely simple solution.

Comment: Note that although this might be a concise solution, all functions are using Quicksort internally that is in O(n²) in worst case (O(n·log n) in average case). So the total complexity is in O(n²) in worst case too.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
$singleOccurences = array_keys(
    array_filter(
        array_count_values(
            array('banana', 'mango', 'banana', 'mango', 'apple' )
        ),
        function($val) {
            return $val === 1;
        }
    )
)
```

See

- [`array_count_values`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) — Counts all the values of an array
- [`array_filter`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) — Filters elements of an array using a callback function
- [`array_keys`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array
- [callbacks](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback)

Comment: @Hannes I don't -- this is elegant :)

Answer (score 2):

Just write your own simple foreach loop:

```
$used = array();    
$array = array("banna","banna","mango","mango","apple");

foreach($array as $arrayKey => $arrayValue){
    if(isset($used[$arrayValue])){
        unset($array[$used[$arrayValue]]);
        unset($array[$arrayKey]);
    }
    $used[$arrayValue] = $arrayKey;
}
var_dump($array); // array(1) { [4]=>  string(5) "apple" }
```

have fun :)

Comment: For some reason I didn't think you could change the size of an array that way during a `foreach`, but it seems to work.

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't declare `$used = array()` before the `foreach` loop?

Comment: @Kendall Hopkins it is not necessary, but you are right in the spirit of good coding standards i will add it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only leave values in the array that are already unique, rather than select one unique instance of each value, you will indeed have to roll your own. Built in functionality is just there to sanitise value sets, rather than filter.

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove any entries that have duplicates, so that you're left with only the entries that were unique in the list?
Hmm it does sound like something you'll need to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

There is no existing function; You'll have to do this in two passes, one to count the unique values and one to extract the unique values:

```
$count = array();
foreach ($values as $value) {
  if (array_key_exists($value, $count))
    ++$count[$value];
  else
    $count[$value] = 1;
}

$unique = array();
foreach ($count as $value => $count) {
  if ($count == 1)
    $unique[] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer on top looks great, but on a side note: if you ever want to eliminate duplicates but leave the first one, using array_flip twice would be a pretty simple way to do so.  array_flip(array_flip(x))

Comment: true, but double flipping has benchmark evidence to suggest that it can outperform array_unique ...there are some pages in StackOverflow that discuss this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Only partially relevant to this specific question - but I created this function from Gumbo's answer for multi dimensional arrays:

```
function get_default($array)
{
    $default = array_column($array, 'default', 'id');
    $array = array_diff($default, array_diff_assoc($default, array_unique($default)));

    return key($array);
}
```

In this example, I had cached statuses and each one other than the default was 0 (the default was 1). I index the `default` array from the IDs, and then turn it into a string. So to be clear - the returned result of this is the ID of the default status providing it's in the same part of the multi dimensional array and not the key of it

Answer (score -1):

PHP.net http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

> `array array_unique  ( array $array  [, int $sort_flags = SORT_STRING  ] )`
>
> Takes an input array and returns a new array without duplicate values.

---

New solution:

```
function remove_dupes(array $array){
    $ret_array = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $val){
        if(count(array_keys($val) > 1){
            continue;
        } else { 
            $ret_array[$key] = $val; 
        }
}
```

Comment: -1 read the example in the question; `array_unique` doesn't work.

Comment: Removes the duplicates, thus making the array contain unique values only. OP, however, want *all* instances of any duplicated value removed, i.e., retain only values which are represented *exactly* once.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. it should work. EDIT: oh, like that.