# PHP Word Crawler

Tags: php, curl

How to get all unique words from a webpage in an array? (without all attributes and javascript etc.)?

Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: uhm, dom -> dom document -> all text content / nodeValue Content -> explode via whitespace to an array -> and then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933760/how-to-remove-all-instances-of-duplicated-values-from-an-array/3933852#3933852  ..have fun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Then do something like:

```
<?php

include_once('simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');

$string = file_get_html('http://www.google.com')->plaintext;
$words = preg_split('/[\s,.]+/', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

var_dump(array_unique($words));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this get_text
this one will help you: http://mel.melaxis.com/devblog/2005/08/06/localizing-php-web-sites-using-gettext/